# SQL - scope_identity() para INSERT SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

Existe algo similar ao `scope_identity()` para me retornar os `ids` criados ao dar um `insert` com base em um `select`? (`insert` de mais de uma linha simultaneamente).

OBS: `scope_identity()` me retorna somente um dos `ids`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filipe, você pode utilizar a cláusula [OUTPUT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms177564.aspx) para gravar em uma variável de tabela (ou mesmo outra tabela) os valores gerados durante a inclusão (instrução [INSERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms174335.aspx)).

Segue modelo, supondo que a tabela Cadastro contenha as colunas ID, Nome e Endereço, sendo que ID possui a propriedade IDENTITY.

```
-- código #1 v2
declare @tbID table (IDnovo int);

INSERT into Cadastro (Nome, Endereço) 
   OUTPUT inserted.ID into @tbID
   VALUES ('João da Silva', 'R. Paracuri, 18'),
          ('Maria da Silva', 'Av. Praia, 2965');

-- lista de novos valores
SELECT Idnovo
  from @tbID;
```

Atento que, se houver procedimento *trigger* associado à tabela, do tipo INSTEAD OF INSERT, este pode afetar o resultado se não estiver corretamente construído.

Comment: Valeu!!!! Perfeito!